# extract multiple audio features using tarosdsp

Tags: java, audio, mfcc

I am using tarosdsp to extract features from audio. I have been able to extract mfcc features. To extract other features such as zero crossing rate, pitch do I need to define new audio dispatcher or I should use the same dispatcher and add audio processor. An example will help.

I can do it separately for mfcc and pitch

```
                    final List<float[]>mfccList = new ArrayList<>(200);
                    String file3= source+'/'+file2.getName();
                    int sampleRate = 44100;
                    int bufferSize = 8192;
                    int bufferOverlap = 128;

                    AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(file3, sampleRate,bufferSize, bufferOverlap);
                    final MFCC mfcc = new MFCC(bufferSize, sampleRate, 40, 50, 300, 3000);
                    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mfcc);                    
                    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioProcessor() {

                        @Override
                        public void processingFinished() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
                            mfcc.process(audioEvent);
                            //final float audio_float[] = mfcc.getMFCC();
                            audio_float=mfcc.getMFCC();
                            //mfccList.add( mfcc.getMFCC());
                            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(audio_float));
```

I would like to save all the features in an array as [mfcc,pitch,zcr]

Answer (score 0):

Use the same dispatcher with a new AudioProcessor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer